# XCode Project: how to easily find all the XIBs that have used a specific image (say, abc.png)

Tags: xcode, image, xib

XCode Project:

How to easily find all the XIBs that have used a specific image (say, abc.png) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a pre-build script action to your current scema using the `/bin/sh` shell and project environment variables enabled, and in the first line put:

```
grep -Ri "abc.png" ${PROJECT_DIR}/*.xib > ~/Desktop/SearchResults.log
```

Then build the project, and on your desktop will be a file containing the file names and lines that contain "abc.png"

Answer (score 0):

simply use your text editor's search function or grep. development xibs are xml.